# Print from drupal to a printer over the internet

Tags: commerce

Hope someone can shed some light on this. I've been asked to develop an ecommerce site in which once the order goes through a receipt will be sent some order details over the internet to a printer without the need of a computer in the middle. This is for a takeway restaurant so I do not know what kind of printer I could use either. Has someone faced a similar problem and could point me in the right direction?

Comment: It would totally depend on a printer - it would need to be connected to the internet directly. Hard, but possible. Then it would need to have webserver built in, serving a printing webservice. I never heard about printer capable of doing that. Then, we would need to know webservice's specification.

Comment: I did think it was something quite tricky, however I did find thermal printers that has web sockets which in turn requires some custom code in order to work. Like you said, difficult but doable. I was wondering if someone has faced similar challenges and could add to the conversation.

Comment: Usually this site is more about getting answers to defined questions, not about conversations.

Comment: Sorry, I've used "conversation" in a manner of speaking as I'm looking for clear answers from people that might have faced the same situation or similar.

Comment: Actually, with [HP ePrint](http://www.hp.com/global/us/en/eprint/what-is-eprint.html) printer all you need is to send email under right address. But anyone can do it, once he happens to grab that address. No way for client to tell if it's legit or no. [Epson provodes true webservice](http://global.epson.com/innovation/technology_articles/201209_02.html) so it is both safer and more complicated. Edit this question when you will select your printer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create batch script on remote PC that connects with your site database and check if it required to print something. Then generate document from database data, and [print it from command line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775908%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi Oleg. Yeah, but ideally I didn't want to use a PC on the printer's end. Only the printer and server.

Comment: Sorry, i'm bad in english. As already was noticed, its hard to find printer that can communicate internet directly. It's because there is to many file formats you can print: text, hypertext, images, and so on. Each of them require specific software or algorythms for decoding. Obviosly, printer have to "understand" each of them. We solved similar issue with therminal printers that placed in supermarket. After the creation of the order we had to print out a check, but we connect to billing system that handles each printer separately. Anyway wish you luck to find what you are really looking for.